# How to update a published app

Tags: c#, winforms

I have published my app(Windows Forms) and the client has started using it. The app is based on a sql database (.sdf file) and now i want to update it . I mean i made some modifications to the sql  tables and now after the client installs the new version of the app it should not  lose the data from database after it updates the application. Is this scenario possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario is commonly referred to as **database migration**. You will need to write a script to transform the existing database to the new format, ideally by importing it into a new sdf file, so you don't damage the original.

Your new app should then be able to work with the new file if all goes well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! When  this script should be called ? Can you give me an example ?

Comment: You can run the script as part of your installation or on the first run of the new version of the app. Ideally, you should detect what version of the database is present when you first read it and upgrade it if necessary. I haven't done this sort of thing for years so I'm not best placed to give an example.